# Django keeps running migrations without changes made

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a custom model field. It basically a one-level dictionary field which allows you to store model-subfields in a JSON manner in the database so fields which wont be queried upon will not take up an extra column.

The issue is, whenever I predefine the default value for the field, the migrations keep thinking there's changes in the default values, and thus makes a new migration.

The default values don't change across migration files, but maybe I am missing something about Django's internals.

How I know it is because of the default values is if I don't set default in the kwargs, the issue does not seem to appear.

The custom field:

```
class JSONStructField(models.JSONField):

    def __init__(self, fields=None, fieldrows=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields = self.process_fields(fields) if fields else None
        self.fieldrows = self.process_fieldrows(fieldrows) if fieldrows else None
        kwargs["default"] = self.generate_default
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def process_fields(fields):
        return [FieldType(**field[2]) if isinstance(field, tuple) else field for field in fields]

    @staticmethod
    def process_fieldrows(fieldrows):
        return [
            [FieldType(**field[2]) if isinstance(field, tuple) else field for field in row]
            for row in fieldrows
        ]

    def generate_default(self):
        default = {}
        if self.fields:
            for field in self.fields:
                default[field.name] = field.default
        elif self.fieldrows:
            for row in self.fieldrows:
                for field in row:
                    default[field.name] = field.default
        else:
            default = None
        return default

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super().formfield(**{
            "widget": JsonInputWidget(fields=self.fields, fieldrows=self.fieldrows),
            **kwargs
        })

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()

        if self.fields:
            kwargs['fields'] = [field.deconstruct() for field in self.fields]

        if self.fieldrows:
            kwargs['fieldrows'] = [
                [field.deconstruct() for field in row] for row in self.fieldrows
            ]

        return name, path, args, kwargs

class FieldType:
    def __init__(self, name: str, label: str, type: str, help_text: str = "", required: bool = False, default: any = None, attrs: dict = None):
        self.name = name
        self.label = label
        self.type = type
        self.help_text = help_text
        self.required = required
        self.default = default
        self.attrs = attrs
    def deconstruct(self):
        return (
            "{0}.{1}".format(self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
            [],
            {
                "name": self.name,
                "label": self.label,
                "type": self.type,
                "help_text": self.help_text,
                "required": self.required,
                "default": self.default,
                "attrs": self.attrs,
            },
        )
```

How the fields are generated:

```
def button_fieldtypes(default_bg, default_text) -> list[FieldType]:
    return [
        [
            FieldType("background_color", "Background Color", "color", default=default_bg),
            FieldType("background_hover_color", "Background Hover Color", "color", default=default_bg),
            FieldType("background_color_active", "Background Active Color", "color", default=default_bg),
            FieldType("background_color_disabled", "Background Disabled Color", "color", default=default_bg),
        ],
        [
            FieldType("text_color", "Text Color", "color", default=default_text),
            FieldType("text_hover_color", "Text Hover Color", "color", default=default_text),
            FieldType("text_color_active", "Text Active Color", "color", default=default_text),
            FieldType("text_color_disabled", "Text Disabled Color", "color", default=default_text),
        ],
        [
            FieldType("border_color", "Border Color", "color", default=default_text),
            FieldType("border_hover_color", "Border Hover Color", "color", default=default_text),
            FieldType("border_color_active", "Border Active Color", "color", default=default_text),
            FieldType("border_color_disabled", "Border Disabled Color", "color", default=default_text),
        ]
    ]
```

```
    info_button = JSONStructField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("Add info button styles to this site"),
        fieldrows=button_fieldtypes("#248782", "#fafafa"),
    )
```

Migration file:

```
# Generated by Django 4.2 on 2023-09-03 14:01

import core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('site_settings', '0003_alter_stylesettings_danger_button_and_more'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stylesettings',
            name='danger_button',
            field=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField(blank=True, default=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField.generate_default, fieldrows=[[('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#872424', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Color', 'name': 'background_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#872424', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Hover Color', 'name': 'background_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#872424', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Active Color', 'name': 'background_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#872424', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Disabled Color', 'name': 'background_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Color', 'name': 'text_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Hover Color', 'name': 'text_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Active Color', 'name': 'text_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Disabled Color', 'name': 'text_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Color', 'name': 'border_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Hover Color', 'name': 'border_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Active Color', 'name': 'border_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Disabled Color', 'name': 'border_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})]], help_text='Add danger button styles to this site', null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stylesettings',
            name='info_button',
            field=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField(blank=True, default=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField.generate_default, fieldrows=[[('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#248782', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Color', 'name': 'background_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#248782', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Hover Color', 'name': 'background_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#248782', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Active Color', 'name': 'background_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#248782', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Disabled Color', 'name': 'background_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Color', 'name': 'text_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Hover Color', 'name': 'text_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Active Color', 'name': 'text_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Disabled Color', 'name': 'text_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Color', 'name': 'border_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Hover Color', 'name': 'border_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Active Color', 'name': 'border_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Disabled Color', 'name': 'border_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})]], help_text='Add info button styles to this site', null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stylesettings',
            name='primary_button',
            field=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField(blank=True, default=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField.generate_default, fieldrows=[[('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#244487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Color', 'name': 'background_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#244487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Hover Color', 'name': 'background_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#244487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Active Color', 'name': 'background_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#244487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Disabled Color', 'name': 'background_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Color', 'name': 'text_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Hover Color', 'name': 'text_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Active Color', 'name': 'text_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Disabled Color', 'name': 'text_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Color', 'name': 'border_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Hover Color', 'name': 'border_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Active Color', 'name': 'border_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Disabled Color', 'name': 'border_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})]], help_text='Add primary button styles to this site', null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stylesettings',
            name='secondary_button',
            field=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField(blank=True, default=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField.generate_default, fieldrows=[[('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#642487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Color', 'name': 'background_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#642487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Hover Color', 'name': 'background_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#642487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Active Color', 'name': 'background_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#642487', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Disabled Color', 'name': 'background_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Color', 'name': 'text_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Hover Color', 'name': 'text_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Active Color', 'name': 'text_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Disabled Color', 'name': 'text_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Color', 'name': 'border_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Hover Color', 'name': 'border_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Active Color', 'name': 'border_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Disabled Color', 'name': 'border_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})]], help_text='Add secondary button styles to this site', null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stylesettings',
            name='success_button',
            field=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField(blank=True, default=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField.generate_default, fieldrows=[[('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#24874d', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Color', 'name': 'background_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#24874d', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Hover Color', 'name': 'background_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#24874d', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Active Color', 'name': 'background_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#24874d', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Disabled Color', 'name': 'background_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Color', 'name': 'text_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Hover Color', 'name': 'text_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Active Color', 'name': 'text_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Disabled Color', 'name': 'text_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Color', 'name': 'border_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Hover Color', 'name': 'border_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Active Color', 'name': 'border_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Disabled Color', 'name': 'border_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})]], help_text='Add success button styles to this site', null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stylesettings',
            name='tertiary_button',
            field=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField(blank=True, default=core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.fields.JSONStructField.generate_default, fieldrows=[[('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#247887', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Color', 'name': 'background_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#247887', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Hover Color', 'name': 'background_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#247887', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Active Color', 'name': 'background_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#247887', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Background Disabled Color', 'name': 'background_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Color', 'name': 'text_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Hover Color', 'name': 'text_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Active Color', 'name': 'text_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Text Disabled Color', 'name': 'text_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})], [('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Color', 'name': 'border_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Hover Color', 'name': 'border_hover_color', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Active Color', 'name': 'border_color_active', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'}), ('core.apps.goodadvice.site_settings.widgets.FieldType', [], {'attrs': None, 'default': '#fafafa', 'help_text': '', 'label': 'Border Disabled Color', 'name': 'border_color_disabled', 'required': False, 'type': 'color'})]], help_text='Add tertiary button styles to this site', null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

I only included one migration file, because they do not seem to change (after running through diff-checker, only the name of migration changes).

A thing to note:
It does work, the default values are properly set. It just keeps making a migration over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep into the code for the Django modelfields, I discovered a method called `_get_default`

After overriding it on the JSONStructField:

```
    @cached_property
    def _get_default(self):
        return self.generate_default
```

there seem to be no more issues.